# How can one Radcombobox is populated based on the value selected on another radcombobox in client side for telerik batch edit (ASP.NET)?

Tags: asp.net, batch-file, telerik, radgrid, radcombobox

I am using two telerik Radcombobox in my page with batch edit capabilities. I have value for one radcombobox. Based on the value selected in the first combobox, the value in the second radcombobox should be changed. Please help me with some client sied solutions

Answer (score 1):

1. hook to the OnClientSelectedIndexChanged event of the first combo: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/client-side-programming/events/onclientselectedindexchanged
2. get a reference to the second one: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/get-client-side-reference
3. Use its set_value() or set_text() method or actually anything you like from the API: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/client-side-programming/objects/radcombobox-object Alternatively, use get_items(), check their properties and select() the desired item if you already have an items list.

EDIT: Some further details based on OP comments:

Batch Edit grid works on the client, so you can't have a pure server solution. Call a webservice when the first combo changes and create the combo box items with JS when the data returns: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/client-side-programming/objects/radcombobox-object.

On getting the reference to the second combo - add a CssClass to it, get its DOM object and use the .control property, as shown in the second article I linked

```
<script>
    function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, args) {
        var secondCombo = $telerik.$(".secondCombo").get(0).control;//add some defensive checks here
        var selectedValue = args.get_item().get_value();
        var desiredItem = secondCombo.findItemByValue(selectedValue);
        if (desiredItem) {
            desiredItem.select();
        }
    }
</script>
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="OnClientSelectedIndexChanged">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="one" Value="1" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="two" Value="2" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="three" Value="3" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox2" runat="server" CssClass="secondCombo">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="first" Value="1" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="second" Value="2" />
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="third" Value="3" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Comment: Since I am using then Radcombobox inside telerik Radgrid, $find("<%=RadComboBox2.ClientID%>"); won't work.

Comment: I need to call the Stored procedures for getting values in the second radcombobox, So server side solution also is fine. Kindly suggest one